# How can I downgrade the iOS on my Ipad 2nd Gen when iTunes says I am "not eligible?

Tags: ios, ipad, restore, downgrade

My ipad 2nd generation is super sluggish and crashing a lot. It was suggested that I downgrade from the current release - which it runs on now - to iOS 7. I tried doing this through itunes and picking my own OS file to restore but I was told the ipad was not eligible for that back up. What is the best way to do that? Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid it's not possible. Apple stops signing iOS releases shortly after the release of a new version, at which point the old version can no longer be installed.

Comment: Ok. Thx. Is the same true of Mac OS? I was in an Apple Store last week with my sluggish 2009 iMac and the genius suggested rolling it back to an older OS for better performance. He was going to do it right then and there but I needed to make sure everything was totally backed up first.

Comment: @Sizzle Please ask a new question for this

Comment: No, for Mac OS X you can install any version that is the same as or later than the version that the machine originally came with, as long as you've kept the install media/file.